# Render from/to areas in Highcharts line chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to achieve in Highcharts a line chart that has from/to areas. For example, in the chart below you can see two from/to areas in gray (Jan 2001/Dec 2001 and Dec 2007/March 2009 respectively). Can this be done in Highcharts?

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be added by [plotBands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands).

```
xAxis: {
        plotBands: [{
            color: '#FCFFC5',
            from: 4.5,
            to: 7.5
        }]
},
```